# Create Objects from Datatable data C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am creating a Web service that takes to input parameters and returns data in objects. I have created a class Sending which has many properties.

I am retrieving the data from a database and loading them into a datatable. I am using datatables because i there can be many rows and i need to create an object of the sending class for each row.

I have also created get and set properties for each variable in the sending class.

Is there any way to insert the data from the datatable into the class objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sample Extension. improve it with your requirement.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToIEnumerable<T>(this DataTable dt)
{
    List<T> list = Activator.CreateInstance<List<T>>();
    T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    var prop = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        T ins = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        foreach (var p in prop)
        {
            try
            {
                p.SetValue(ins, dr[p.Name], null);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        list.Add(ins);
    }
    return list;
}
```

usage:

`yourDataTable.ToIEnumerable<YourClassModel>();`

Answer (score 2):

If you have already created matching datamodel, then you can do something like this

```
IList<YourClass> items = yourdatatable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
    new YourClass
        {
            field1 = x.Field<int>("idcolumnName"),
            field2 = x.Field<string>("otherColumn")
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you have a link for how to use reflections?

Comment: @Lahib how do you survive without knowing the .NET documentation? As Reflection is a core part of the .NET framework - guess what, it is in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do this by hand. ORMs do exactly this job in a much easier way. You can actually use a Micro-ORM like [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) or [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) to load data from the database as objects with a minimum of configuration.

For example, this query Dapper.NET query will load all Dog objects with the specified age:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    ...
}            

var dogs = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age", new { Age = 5 });
```